# Apache PIG - How to change the standard output name "part-r-00000" of files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have a .pig script which creates a file with some calculated data. 
I want to have the output file named "result.txt" instead of the meaningless standard output name "part-r-00000".

The last entry in my .pig script is

> store C into 'result' USING PigStorage();

Therefore "result" is the name of the folder in HDFS where the result.txt should be stored.

How can I do this?

Comment: There are bunch of storage methods available in org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage .. You can try those..

Answer (score 1):

The `part-r-XXXXX` are not meaningless depending on how you plan to use them.  If you need to load the results of this pig script into another pig script you can just do:

```
A = LOAD 'result' USING PigStorage() AS (...) ;
```

As `LOAD` can take a directory as input and will load each file in that directory.

If you **need** to handle the output (locally) as a single text file, then there is nothing builtin to PIG that will accomplish that. You will need to write a script to pull the results from hdfs and concatenate all of the `part-r-XXXXX` files together.